# SQL Find qty for children lot but not parent lot

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a situation where we can create splits from a parent lot, and treat the child lot as their own "production lot". There are also two quantities associated with the parent and child, as shown below

The table ends up looking like so:

| Lot | CntType | Qty | Scrap Qty | Confirmed Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Parent | 50 | 3 | 88 |
| A-1 | Child | 11 | 2 | 5 |
| A-2 | Child | 32 | 3 | 8 |
| B | Parent | 100 | 10 | 17 |
| B-1 | Child | 10 | 3 | 8 |

What I would like to do is ignore the parent values for Qty and Confirmed Qty but show their scrap, but show all the qty values for the children; in the end of the day, I would like a table as shown below:

| Lot | CntType | Qty | Scrap Qty | Confirmed Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Parent | Null | 3 | Null |
| A-1 | Child | 11 | 2 | 5 |
| A-2 | Child | 32 | 3 | 8 |
| B | Parent | Null | 10 | Null |
| B-1 | Child | 10 | 3 | 8 |

I am kind of stuck here in this requirement and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `Select .. case when CntType ='Parent' then null else Qty end qty ..`

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING. Thank you!

Comment: For an SSRS expression, you could also use `=SUM(IIF(Fields!CntType.Value = "Child", Fields!Qty.Value, 0))`